# LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE) is this possible?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `Person` and `Salary`.

`Person`:

```
PersonId   |  Name   |   Surname
--------------------------------
       1      John          Deer
       2      Mark          Bear
```

`Salary`:

```
SId | PersonId | Date                       | Salary
----------------------------------------------------
1            2   2013-01-01 00:00:00.000      100
2            2   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000      90
3            2   2011-01-01 00:00:00.000      80
```

What I am trying to do is, if a person has a salary record then it should display the most current salary info in the results, if no salary record then it should display the salary info as null, which is like...

```
Result
------------------------------------------------------------------------
PersonId   |   Name   | Surname  |  Date                      |  Salary
       1       John        Deer     NULL                            NULL
       2       Mark        Bear     2013-01-01 00:00:00.000         100
```

I know it has to be something like this but with lack of knowledge I just couldn't achieve..

```
SELECT 
    P.PersonId, P.Name, P.Surname, SL.Date, SL.Salary
FROM 
    PERSON P
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 S.PersonId, S.Date, S.Salary 
     FROM Salary 
     WHERE S.PersonId = P.PersonId ORDER BY Date DESC) SL
```

Comment: You're almost there - now that you have set up your JOIN, all that's missing is a `...) SL ON P.PersonId = SL.PersonId` **join condition** to link those two sets of data together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by ranking the salaries by person and date with a CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. This will put the most recent salary by person in descending order in the first position, which we can filter for later (where rank = 1). After that, it becomes a simple `LEFT JOIN` from `Person` to the aliased CTE:

```
WITH RankedSalaries AS
(
    SELECT 
        PersonId
        ,Date
        ,Salary
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Salary
)
SELECT 
    p.PersonId
    ,p.Name
    ,p.Surname
    ,s.Date
    ,s.Salary
FROM
    Person p
LEFT JOIN
    RankedSalaries s
    ON
    p.PersonId = s.PersonId
WHERE
    s.RowNum = 1
```

Alternatively, you could take the contents of the CTE and move it in between the parenthesis of the query you started (i.e. `LEFT JOIN (<CTE query>)`). Just remember to add the `= 1` constraint.